# Почтовый сервер на Ubuntu

Tags: postfix, email, ubuntu

Какой почтовый сервер выбрать для своего сайта? На сайте есть возможность переписки между пользователями. Когда один пользователь пишет другому, помимо нотификации на сайте, второму участнику отправляется письмо и на почту. Хочу поднять свой почтовый сервер. ОС Ubuntu 10.4. Порылся, нашел пока два: postfix и exim4. Кокой из них лучше? Может есть и другие? Желательно, чтобы в пакет сервера был включен веб интерфейс, для доступа к ящику, к примеру, я заведу там админский ящик, и хочу просматривать почту не используя третисторонних лиц (mail.ru, yandex и т.д.).

Comment: А зачем почтовый сервер?? Одно но, письмо может быть остановлено спам фильтром, который будет проверять наличие почтового сервера. В других случаях можно использовать функцию mail();

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса не очевидна необходимость предоставления локальным пользователям почтового адреса в домене сервиса. Для описанной задачи - отправлять письма на внешние почтовые адреса с возможностью просмотра администратором всего отправленного - почтовый сервер вам не нужен. Любой локальный  MTA сгодится для отправки почты, отправленное можно складывать в любом удобном для просмотра администратором виде - хоть в виде текстовых файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не могу сказать насчет exim4, у postfix есть админка, при грамотной настройке спама будет минимум, так же у него есть и вебморда, достаточно функциональная. Конечно некоторые вещи надо допилить в стандартном пакете, но в общем то я уже 3 года сижу на этом почтовом сервере, спам последний раз я видел уже месяцев 5 назад.